# Google API with / without key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile

Which one is the best way (with or without key) to use Google map in mobile app to show location? I am able to show location without key using this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false .
But people are saying that this is not correct way. Is there any limitation to use Google API without key? What is the purpose of having key for google API?

Please suggest me the best way to do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API limits non business users to 2,500 requests per day. If you don't provide a key, the request are limited by your IP-address. If you do provide a key, the quota limits are per-key instead of per-IP-address. You can also use a key to monitor your application's API usage.